# Python : How to prompt user to enter numbers to an empty list?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So, I know how to calculate a `list: list = [],` but I want to ask the user to enter random numbers; however, if the user enters 0, then it quits, which means the

```
list is : [number1, number2, number3, ..., 0].
```

I tried to write: l`ist = input ("Please enter number: ", []),` but it seems it's not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a `while` loop to keep the program going until the user enters a 0.

```
# Don't call this 'list', it's a reserved keyword in python
lst = []

user_input = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

while user_input != 0:
  lst.append(user_input)

  user_input = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

print("You said: " + lst)
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to duplicate your `input` line, you can use a break instead:

```
lst = []

while True:
  user_input = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

  if user_input == 0:
    break

  lst.append(user_input)

print("You said: " + lst)
```

Comment: It's certainly a bad idea to use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type, but `list` _isn't_ a reserved word, otherwise it'd be a SyntaxError to use it as a variable name. Eg, see what happens if you try and do `for = 4`.

Comment: I know, Python doesn't have a concept of reserved words. But they really should be treated that way, even if they aren't *literally* reserved. Especially for someone who is just starting out, you will get some really funny errors that are near impossible to diagnose if you start using syntactical names for your variables and functions

Comment: Things like for, while, def, etc are reserved. But yes, the error messages can be confusing when you try to use a type name that you've re-bound to something else.

Comment: @user2896976 Thanks! However, your way keeps popping up "Please enter a number". Is there way to ask the user once and let the user continue entering numbers until he or she enters 0? Like "Please enter numbers: 39 59 100 39 0".

Comment: @user2896976 There is an error: print("You said: " + lst)
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Comment: You could say `print("Please enter a number: ", end="")` before your loop and then do `input()` with no message. For printing out the list try `print("You said: %s" % lst)`

Comment: @user2896976 Or just let `print` do the conversion to string: `print("You said:", lst)`